# Why those integral limits are wrong?

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $$\displaystyle{ f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \frac18 & |x|+|y|\leq 2 \\ 0 & |x|+|y|>2 \end{array}\right. }$$ be density function of continuous random variable $X,Y$. for every $|y|<2$ find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$

So my idea here was to find $f_y$ and than use the formula of $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

so the  because $|x| \leq 2-|y|$ I can say that $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ and than $$f_Y = \int_{-2}^{2}f_{X,Y}dx$$.

Why is this wrong?

Comment: How does that integral help you compute $f_Y(y)$? I don't see $y$ anywhere in that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this wrong?

Because $(X,Y)$ support is a square with vertices $(0,2);(2,0);(0,-2);(-2,0)$

thus integrating you get

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{8}\int_{-2-y}^{y+2}dx=\frac{y+2}{4}$$

for $-2<y\leq 0$

and

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{8}\int_{y-2}^{2-y}dx=\frac{2-y}{4}$$

for $0<y<2$

Concluding:

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{y+2}{4}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-2;0)}(y)+\frac{2-y}{4}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(y)$$

... a triangle distribution

Comment: but I still not understand what I did wrong here, I understand how the support of $X,Y$ looks like

Comment: @Sagigever Added some details. Do a drawing, derive the equations of the lines which define the joint support and integrate as I showed. If my answer has been useful I will appreciate if you marked it as accepted

Comment: Ohh, now I understood how should I treat the condtion $|y|<2$, thank you for your answer. much appreaciated